# Switching between buttons state in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making simple flutter app with three custom buttons, when im clicking on one button it change background color on this button. What i want to achieve is when i am clicking on button when other button is activated i want to deactivate button and activate button that i just clicked.
Custom button is represented by  CircleButton class and im using three of these in my main build in HomePageClass.

I wonder where it should be to turn off and turn on the appropriate buttons, it seems to me that everything should be handled in the CircleButton class.

Circle button class:

```dart
class CircleButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final String imageData;
  final String buttonName;
  CircleButton({this.onPressed, this.imageData, this.buttonName});
  @override
  _CircleButtonState createState() => _CircleButtonState();
}

class _CircleButtonState extends State<CircleButton> {
  bool _active = false;
  //bool isButtonActive = false;
  void handleTap() {
    setState(() {
      /*
      if(widget.buttonName == 'Mode'){
      }
      if(widget.buttonName =='Sounds'){
      }
      if(widget.buttonName =='Volume'){
      }
      isButtonActive = !isButtonActive;
      */
      _active = !_active;
      widget.onPressed();
    });
    //print('widget.isActive:' + isButtonActive.toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double circleBoxSize = 50.0;
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
          onPressed: handleTap,
          child: new Container(
            width: circleBoxSize,
            height: circleBoxSize,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                gradient: _active
                    ? LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                        end: Alignment.topRight,
                        colors: [
                            Color.fromRGBO(79, 172, 254, 1),
                            Color.fromRGBO(0, 242, 245, 1)
                          ])
                    : null,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: _active ? null : Color.fromRGBO(227, 230, 238, 1)),
            child: new Image.asset(
              this.widget.imageData,
              color: _active ? Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1) : null,
              scale: 1.8,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 14),
        new Text(
          this.widget.buttonName,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: "Roboto",
              fontSize: 14,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(140, 151, 173, 1),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

HomePage where i'm using CircleButton objects:

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool _active = false;
  int iter = 0;
  String activeButton;
  List<String> selectBarData = ['dasdasdas'];
  List<String> modes = ['deep-sleep', 'pain-relief'];
  List<String> sounds = ['campfire', 'rain'];

  void handleButtonsPress(){
    setState(){

    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25, top: 60),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <CircleButton>[
                  new CircleButton(
                    onPressed: handleButtonsPress,
                    imageData: 'assets/body-organ.png',
                    buttonName: 'Mode',
                  ),
                  new CircleButton(
                    onPressed: handleButtonsPress,
                    imageData: 'assets/audio.png',
                    buttonName: 'Sounds',
                  ),
                  new CircleButton(
                    onPressed: handleButtonsPress,
                    imageData: 'assets/speaker.png',
                    buttonName: 'Volume',
                  )
                ],
              )),
          selectBar()
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

when im starting app and im clicking first button it looks like that:

[image]

when im clicking second button it looks like that:

[image]

but i want result like that:

[image]

Comment: I think I know what's wrong let me try testing it.

Comment: Okay, thank you Antony

Comment: Just answered it! Didn't get to test it but I can help if there are any problems

Comment: Thank you, i'll check it in one hour when im back home

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have an opportunity to test this but it should work. I created a `ValueChange` callback that returns the assigned tag of the button to the parent. This allows you to change the state (active or not) of the button based on whether the `_active` is equivalent to the tag of the button. Hopefully, this makes sense. Here is the code, there are comments in some of the parts I changed. If you have any questions or problems let me know!

Home:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String _active;
  int iter = 0;
  String activeButton;
  List<String> selectBarData = ['dasdasdas'];
  List<String> modes = ['deep-sleep', 'pain-relief'];
  List<String> sounds = ['campfire', 'rain'];

  // ValueChanged<String> callback
  void active(String btn) {
    setState(() => _active = btn);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25, top: 60),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <CircleButton>[
                  new CircleButton(
                    action: active, //pass data from child to parent
                    tag: "button1", //specifies attribute of button
                    active: _active == "button1" ? true : false, //set button active based on value in this parent
                    imageData: 'assets/body-organ.png',
                    buttonName: 'Mode',
                  ),
                  new CircleButton(
                    action: active,
                    tag: "button2",
                    active: _active == "button2" ? true : false,
                    imageData: 'assets/audio.png',
                    buttonName: 'Sounds',
                  ),
                  new CircleButton(
                    action: active,
                    tag: "button3",
                    active: _active == "button2" ? true : false,
                    imageData: 'assets/speaker.png',
                    buttonName: 'Volume',
                  )
                ],
              )),
          selectBar()
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Button:

```
class CircleButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueChanged<String> action; //callback value change
  final String tag; //tag of button
  final String imageData;
  final String buttonName;
  final bool active; // state of button
  CircleButton({this.action, this.imageData, this.buttonName, this.active, this.tag});
  @override
  _CircleButtonState createState() => _CircleButtonState();
}

class _CircleButtonState extends State<CircleButton> {
  void handleTap() {
    setState(() {
      widget.action(widget.tag);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double circleBoxSize = 50.0;
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
          onPressed: handleTap,
          child: new Container(
            width: circleBoxSize,
            height: circleBoxSize,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                gradient: widget.active
                    ? LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                        end: Alignment.topRight,
                        colors: [
                            Color.fromRGBO(79, 172, 254, 1),
                            Color.fromRGBO(0, 242, 245, 1)
                          ])
                    : null,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: widget.active ? null : Color.fromRGBO(227, 230, 238, 1)),
            child: new Image.asset(
              this.widget.imageData,
              color: widget.active ? Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1) : null,
              scale: 1.8,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 14),
        new Text(
          this.widget.buttonName,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: "Roboto",
              fontSize: 14,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(140, 151, 173, 1),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Hopefully, this is helpful!

Comment: I tested your code and now it works like this: when im clicking on button1, it activates but when im clicking second time on button1 to desactivate him it didnt work, when button1 is activated and im clicking on button2, button1 is desactivated but button3 is activated too with button2, when im clicking on them, they cant desactivate.

Comment: I will take a look tomorrow sorry it didn’t work. I couldn’t test it at the time so I was winging it.